# Problems with select query

Tags: sql, database, select, ado.net

[image]

Hi, I have included an image of my tables , What I want to do is `select top 6 from product detail whose state=1` in feauture state. Any help will be appreciated . I was thinking of something like:

```
Select TOP 6 [productName] As test, [productDetail] AS test1 
From [productDetail] 
INNER JOIN test ON productDetail.makeID = feautureState.makeID 
Where feautureState.state='1';
```

but its not working :(

Comment: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'test'.

Comment: hi try to call tables as `dbo.tablename` in the query

Comment: Your inner join is to a "test" entity which you have not specified in the schema diagram. Is this an error in "sanitizing" this query or is this what you're actually running? If it's the latter, there's your problem; it should probably be "featureState".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

join to a table name not a column name

```
Select TOP 6 [productName] As test, [productDetail] AS test1
From [productDetail]
JOIN [featureState] ON productDetail.makeID=feautureState.makeID
Where feautureState.state='1';
```

Comment: why u have used join instead of innerjoin

Comment: they are functionally equivalent. you can use either join or inner join in this case

Comment: "Inner" and "Outer" are inferrable keywords; "Join" is inferred to be "Inner Join", while a "Left Join" is equivalent to "Left Outer Join".

Comment: i m still unclear about this join world , can u provide me with the simplest example or ny tutorial which can crystal clear my concept , thnx in advance:)

Answer (score 2):

this should work.

also, is state a string or an integer?

```
Select top 6 pd.ProductName,pd.ProductDetail
from dbo.ProductDetail pd
inner join dbo.FeatureState fs on pd.makeid=fs.makeid
where fs.state=1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select top 6 pd.productName, pd.productDetail
from productDetail pd
    Inner Join feautureState  fs on fs.makeID = pd.makeID
where fs.state = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 6
  pd.productName,
  pd.productDetail
FROM dbo.productDetail pd
INNER JOIN dbo.featureState fs on fs.makeID = pd.makeID
WHERE fs.makeID = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

INNER JOIN "test" -> this is not a table

Answer (score 1):

Your inner join is to a "test" entity which you have not specified in the schema diagram. Is this an error in "sanitizing" this query or is this what you're actually running? If it's the latter, there's your problem; it should probably be "featureState".

Answer (score 1):

Your inner join should say the table name you are joining to.  Also, my guess is that state is an int, not a varchar, so no quotes are necessary.

```
Select TOP 6 [productName], [productDetail] 
From [productDetail] 
INNER JOIN featureState ON productDetail.makeID = feautureState.makeID 
Where feautureState.state = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said you can correct your query with the following.

```
SELECT TOP 6 [productName] As test, [productDetail] AS test1 
FROM [productDetail] 
INNER JOIN featureState ON productDetail.makeID = feautureState.makeID 
WHERE feautureState.state='1';
```

However, you need to specify an `ORDER BY` clause otherwise the results you get will be unpredictable.

Also from your schema diagram, you have a one to one relationship with `ProductDetail` and `FeatureState`, perhaps the state flag should be a column in your `ProductDetail` table? But it's possible that you are only giving a simplified version of your database.

Edit ---- In response to comments.

To add a column to an existing table, assuming you have data.

```
ALTER TABLE ProductDetail
  ADD FeatureState BIT NULL
```

Or you can set to not null and give a default value for all existing rows

```
ALTER TABLE ProductDetail
  ADD FeatureState BIT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_ProductDetail_FeatureState] DEFAULT (0)
```

Comment: Well I havent include state column in the product detail , I did a relationship between these two tables and set the insert property to cascade , so that when a new product is added the feauturestate table should also be updated, is it the right way of doing it

Comment: If a single product, has a single feature state flag, then there is no need for a second table and FK relationship. Just add a featurestate column to your productdetail table.

Comment: ok thnx will do that , one more thing is there any simple of adding the column to the current table , coz I then have to delete everything and recreate the table , and have to copy all the cells plus delete the relationshiops.

Comment: I've ammended the answer, it should simplify your query.

Comment: thnx a lot .. I wish uni had thought me all this stuff ,, programming is all about self study ..

Comment: That's the beauty of it, always something to learn, never gets dull.

Comment: Also can i alter the default value of any column ?

Answer (score -1):

The Below statement is one of the solution of your Problem.

Select Top 6 * 
From dbo.productDetail
Where makelid in 
             (Select makelid 
              from dbo.feautureState 
              where State = 1
             )